# Add relationships to existing data in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To start with Neo4j (4.2.3) I loaded a year's worth of flights data (7m rows) and wanted to try and model a flight as a relationship between origin and destination airport. However the following query just eats up memory and has not finished after two days, so something is clearly amiss:

```
MATCH (f:Flight), (dest:Airport), (orig:Airport)
WHERE f.Dest = dest.IATA_Code AND f.Origin = orig.IATA_Code
CREATE (orig)-[r:FlightTo {DeptDateTime:f.DepDT, ArriveDateTime:f.ArrDT, Flight:f.Name}]->(dest)
```

I can do this instead:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///flights.csv' AS row
MERGE (o:Org_Airport {Org_IATA:row.Origin})
MERGE (d:Dest_Airport {Dest_IATA:row.Dest})
CREATE (o)-[r:FlightTo {DeptDateTime:row.DepDT, ArriveDateTime:row.ArrDT, Flight:row.Name}]->(d)
```

While this has the advantage of working (even in a reasonable time) it feels ugly to essentially duplicate the airports and also to go through the CSV file again when all the required data is already in the database.
I'm not quite there with my graph thinking probably so I'd appreciate some guidance on what the best way is to add a relationship like this, keeping in mind that original load files might get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes set? Looking at your first query, you'd need:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Flight(Dest);
CREATE INDEX ON :Airport(IATA_Code);
```

If you don't have indexes/constraints set on the label/property, the look up/merge will be very slow.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I had both of those indexes created before running the first query, so that's not it.